# Deserialization of Arrays in XML response

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm still struggling with deserialization of XML containing arrays of items.

The response I want to deserialize:

```
<ns1:OperationResult xmlns:ns1="http://xxxx.com">
            <done>false</done>
            <errorEntities>
                 <elements>
                      <entityID>100014</entityID>
                      <entityType>GROUP</entityType>
                      <errors>
                           <errorCode>INVALID_DATA</errorCode>
                           <errorMessage>s: d3f62887-a2a3-4cde-8f8b-09812a7bd011ed8d385e-f4c4-4fae-9a4b-1ba405db54b6-MessageTemplate:{k2.constraints.numberFormat.length}|length:5|; </errorMessage>
                      </errors>
                 </elements>
            </errorEntities>
</ns1:OperationResult>
```

And this is my corresponding class:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxxx.", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "OperationResult")]
public class GroupCreateUpdateResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "done")]
    public string done { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorEntities")]
    public ErrorEntities errorEntities { get; set; }

    public bool hasErrors => done == "true" ? true : false;
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "errorEntities")]
public class ErrorEntities
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "elements")]
    public List<ErrorElements> elements { get; } = new List<ErrorElements>();
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "elements")]
public class ErrorElements
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entityId")]
    public string entityId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entityType")]
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errors")]
    Errors errors { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "errors")]
public class Errors
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorCode")]
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorMessage")]
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I have already a method deserializing my responses. Actually I am struggling with this specific one. Alle others without arrays are working fine.

What I finally get is this:

[image]

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `Paste XML as Classes`?

Comment: Yes and it works if done like this. The problem is, that all my other classes are defined like the one above and they work fine like that. If done like you suggested, it will break the definition structure of my other classes or I need to redo all of them. Maybe there is something I missed in my way of declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues

1) The namespace in the xml and the classes have to be the same

2) The tags names in the classes are case sensitive so you have to make sure the spelling is correct (Upper/Lower Case)

3) The class object have to be public otherwise the tags are ignored.

4) Where there are no namespaces in XML (and parent has a namespace) you need the empty string for the namespaces

See corrected code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GroupCreateUpdateResult));

            GroupCreateUpdateResult group = (GroupCreateUpdateResult)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://com.f24.soap.fwi.schema", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "OperationResult")]
    public class GroupCreateUpdateResult
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "done", Namespace = "")]
        public string done { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorEntities", Namespace = "")]
        public ErrorEntities errorEntities { get; set; }

        //public bool hasErrors => done == "true" ? true : false;
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "errorEntities")]
    public class ErrorEntities
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "elements", Namespace = "")]
        public List<ErrorElements> elements { get; set;}
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "elements")]
    public class ErrorElements
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "entityID")]
        public string entityId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "entityType")]
        public string entityType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "errors", Namespace = "")]
        public Errors errors { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "errors")]
    public class Errors
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorCode")]
        public string errorCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorMessage")]
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I was so blind -.- You saved me, thank you very much...it works now :)